# Google Maps autocomplete in Bootstrap modal with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, vue.js, autocomplete

I have Boostrap modal with `<input>`. I have implemented Google autocomplete for it with the following well-known trick:

```
.pac-container {
    z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```

Now I'm struggling to make autocomplete working inside 2nd layer Boostrap Modal. Unfortunately, the `z-index` trick doesn't work here.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editItemModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div id="editItem" class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    Update Address <b>{{selectedItem.properties.NAME}}</b>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="editItem_ADRESS1"></label>
                            <input v-model="selectedItem.properties.ADRESS1" type="text" class="form-control" id="editItem_ADRESS1" ref="editItem_ADRESS1" placeholder="{{selectedItem.properties.ADRESS1}}">
                        </div>    
                    </form>          
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-ok" @click="save_item()" data-dismiss="modal">Save</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then comes the Vue object

```
const editItem = new Vue({
            el: "#editItem",
            data: {
                items: null,
                selectedItem: null,
            },
            methods: {
                save_item() {
                    this.selectedItem = itemsList.selectedItem;
                    var ip = location.host;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: 'http://' + ip + '/updateItem',
                        data: {
                              command: "edit_item",
                              item_id: this.selectedItem.id,
                              adress1: this.selectedItem.properties.ADRESS1
                        },
                        success: function (responseData) {
                            if (responseData.result === false) {
                                console.log(responseData.result);
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("successfully updated");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.log('error', error);
                            }
                        }); // end of ajax
                    } // end od save_item()
                } // end of methods
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to figure out what was the issue. It turns out that the DOM object is not created yet by Vue when the Google `iniAutocomplete()` function sets listeners.

In addition, my `<input>` didn't run the Google `geolocate()` function. That's how the `<input>` looks now:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="edit-item_ADRESS1"></label>
        <input id="edit-item_ADRESS1" v-model="selectedItem.properties.ADRESS1" type="text" class="form-control" onFocus="geolocate('edit-item')">
</div>
```

The next step was to make a minor change in the `geolocate()` function. I pass `action` variable `onFocus` event and use it to determine what DOM object initiated the call.

```
if (action == "add-item") {
      autocomplete_add_item.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
}
if (action == "edit-item") {
      // we need to run iniAutocomplete again after the  DOM object was finally created by Vue
      initAutocomplete();
      autocomplete_edit_item.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
}
```